# Installing Spring tool suite

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am trying to install Spring tool suite.

when I downloaded it from https://spring.io/tools#suite-three, it gave a .jar file like spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.1.RELEASE-e4.17.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar

How can I install this and use, earlier I use to get .zip file from spring wb site.

Answer (score 19):

The JAR file is a self-extracting JAR file. As long as you have a JRE or JDK installed on your Windows machine, you should be able to double-click the JAR file and it will self-extract the content on disc - which is basically the unzip operation that you did before.

In case the double click doesn't work, you can go to the terminal and execute `java -jar spring-tool-suite-4-4.8.1.RELEASE-e4.17.0-win32.win32.x86_64.self-extracting.jar`. This will also run the unzip of the content.

Comment: It seems to unzip the content by default into your default user directory, check for it there.

Answer (score 1):

First follow all the steps to install Java/JDK on your machine. Once that is done, you should be able to extract the STS folder by simply double clicking the jar file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).